# The text from PDF file is not printing in Linux by non-root user from bash terminal

Tags: linux, printers, cups, lpr

I am trying to print an ordinary PDF file with some filled table in it from the bash terminal. When I do it as `root` everything is okay, but when I trying to print it as `non-root` user I see only tables border lines and graphics printed with no text at all.

I ended up here after hours or researching in the web. Could anyone help please?

I am using the following command to print the file:

```
lp -d MG2500 /path_to_the_file
```

I thought that the non-root user should have an access to the fonts. I gave him the permissions with the following commands:

```
setfacl -m u:User:rx /usr/share/fonts
setfacl -m u:User:rx /usr/share/fonts/*
```

but with no success. The result was the same: The printer did not print any letters. Only tables border lines and graphics.

My system is:
*Ubuntu Server 23.04*

My printer is:
*Canon MG2540S (driver MG2500)*

Comment: Check permissions of the spool directory used by the printer driver `/var/spool/cups/`. Make sure that the user who is printing has write access to this directory. After changing permissions restart cups service `sudo systemctl restart cups`.
If that's doesn't help check driver files permissions of the printing user, make sure he can read.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But  unfortunately nothing helped though I granted 'rwx' access to '/var/spool/cups' '/usr/share/ppd' '/usr/share/cups' (all with subfolders) and restarted cups service. Even rebooted the server itself. But with not success. Again no text - only tables borders and pictures.

Comment: Check if fonts are installed in root directory `/root/.local/share/fonts/`, do you have same fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/`?
You can also run a command `fc-list` under each user to see installed fonts.

Comment: I have all fonts installed in `/usr/share/fonts/` and I had no folder `/root/.local/share/fonts` so I created it, copied everything there from the first folder and recached them by `fc-cache -fv` but still no success. I also provided `rwx` permissions to it for the required user of course.

Comment: The problem is definitely with some resources permissions. Few more things to check: directory `/usr/share/cups/` permissions; compare output of `lp` command with option `-o job-sheets=none` to see if there any differences in driver settings under root and other user. Try to create one more user and print under his account.